# In Swift, why does Calendar nextDate/enumerateDates methods with backward direction does not provide a date before September 1995?

Tags: swift, calendar, foundation

I’m trying to get the previous date that matches the 9nth month in the Gregorian calendar (which is September) from Date.now (which is in December 2023 right now). The expected date is then in 2023. The first date returned is in 1995 for my time zone. Why?

I filed the feedback FB13462533

```
let matchingDateComponents: DateComponents = DateComponents(month: 09)
                        
let date: Date? = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.nextDate(
    after: Date.now,
    matching: matchingDateComponents,
    matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
    direction: .backward
)
            
print(date) // Optional(1995-08-31 23:00:00 +0000)
```

I just tested with other time zones and the results are different... For some time zones, the result is correct, for others, not.

- Europe/London, Optional(**1970**-08-31 23:00:00 +0000)
- Europe/Paris, Optional(**1995**-08-31 23:00:00 +0000)
- Europe/Vilnius, Optional(**2002**-08-31 22:00:00 +0000)
- America/Los_Angeles, Optional(**2023**-09-01 07:00:00 +0000)

I used the following code to print the result for all time zones.

```
for zone in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
    var calendar: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: zone) ?? .autoupdatingCurrent
                
    let matchingDateComponents: DateComponents = DateComponents(month: 9)
                
    let date: Date? = calendar.nextDate(
        after: Date.now,
        matching: matchingDateComponents,
        matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
        direction: .backward
    )
                
    print(zone, date)
}
```

Comment: So any problem in always setting the time zone to GMT for instance? As far as I understand it the nextDate and enumerateDate functions can be quite buggy so if you have a solution that works go for it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I started to see that these nextDate/enumerateDates are buggy yes... I'm wondering if I should avoid them. I'm using them to calculate previous/next date for recurring events (like in Calendar.app or Reminders.app when you specify monthly, yearly etc.). I'll try to see if I can obtain better results using GMT, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `dateByAddingComponents`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH can you explain please?

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to achieve, look's like you can use Calendar's dateByAddingComponents